# Crystal report .rpt file in visual studio 2012 shows binary format instead of design

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

We developed an application in visual studio 2010 and reports are working fine, when we choose to open the same application through visual studio 2012 Ultimate, reports are not working and when i open .rpt file showing binary format ad also I could not find Crystalreport.rpt in Reporting template in visual studio 2012. After googling it, I have installed
CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_5 , but doesn't work.

How can i change or edit .rpt file design using visual studio 2012 and want to change the .rpt database name too. Any suggestion or idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem after installing visual studio 2012 and found no answer on the forums. I uninstalled CR yesterday and downloaded again the CRForVS 13.0.5 from [here](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) just in case there was a bug in the previous version I downloaded in may and installed it. Then I installed update 3 for Visual studio and everything works fine now.
Cheers
Michael

Comment: thanks for the reply..i will try to uninstall and install .exe that u have provided in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I figure this one out for me.

From SAP Crystal Reports's download site:

> Please note: To integrate "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft > Visual Studio" you must run the Install Executable. Running the MSI will not ? >fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS. MSI files by definition are for runtime >distribution only.
>   By default Windows 10 does not install the 3.5 framework, CR for VS still needs >it. Select it by "Turn Windows feature on or off" and choose both options.

I downloaded the exe, instead of the MSI packages, and it worked for me finally. Helps to read I guess.